# Yii2 - Renderizar una vista desde una subcarpeta

Tags: yii2, views, server-side-rendering

Estoy trabajando en **Yii2**. Quería saber cuál es la forma correcta de **renderizar** desde el controlador una vista que se encuentra dentro de una **subcarpeta** en el directorio views. Por ejemplo, tengo la siguiente situación:

```
views
-campus (carpeta)
--actividad (subcarpeta)
---2020.php (vista)
```

Intenté las siguientes opciones pero sin resultado:

1. $this->render('/actividad/2020',[]); return
2. $this->render('/actividad/2020',[],$this->context); return
3. $this->render('2020',[],$this->context); return
4. $this->render('@app/views/campus/actividad/2020',[]); return
5. $this->render('//actividad/2020',[]);

Desde ya gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que la ruta principal viene con el mismo nombre que tu controller y es a partir de ahi que puedes ir construyendo la ruta. Ejemplo

```
CampusController
  actionIndex 
   $this->render('index');
```

Ira a la ruta views/campus/index.php

Si tu quieres ir a otra carpeta debe ser a partir de campus por ejemplo si quieres ir a

> campus/actividad/2020.php

La ruta del render debería ser

```
$this->render('actividad/2020');
```

Lo que te sobra es la "/" del principió en tus intentos , es decir tu intento 1 ha de cambiar de

```
$this->render('/actividad/2020',[]); return
```

a

```
$this->render('actividad/2020',[]); return
```